# plotly trendline that doesn't make sense

Tags: plotly, regression, trendline

Trying to map a trendline in plotly for the first time, and I'm getting results that don't make sense. First, the line isn't straight (it's overfitted, but in a way that doesn't make sense). Second, even if the line were straightened out, its angle doesn't make sense.

Clearly, I'm doing something wrong, and I suspect it's simple/fundamental . . . but I can't spot it. Thanks in advance!

[image: plotly scatter graph, with nonsensical and nonlinear trendline]

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df=pd.DataFrame()
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(['2020-04-01','2020-05-01','2020-06-01','2020-07-01','2020-08-01','2020-09-01','2020-10-01','2020-11-01','2020-12-01','2021-01-01','2021-02-01','2021-03-01'])
df['views']=[7942, 114511, 192292, 230733, 272823, 271613, 274803, 227554, 270407, 284185, 307765, 329814]

fig= px.scatter(
    df, 
    x='month', 
    y='views', 
    opacity=1,
    trendline='ols',
    trendline_scope='overall'
)
fig.show()
```

Comment: I get a meaningful trend line.  had to `pip install statsmodels` to make it work.  plotly  5.2.1

Comment: thanks @RobRaymond, although I have statsmodels (v 0.9.0) installed and plotly is v 5.2.2. What kind of trend line do you get?

Comment: statsmodels 0.12.2 - trend line is a straight line `'y': array([116935.00433026, 137519.53410726, 158790.21487683, 179374.74465384,
                 200645.42542341, 221916.10619298, 242500.63596998, 263771.31673955,
                 284355.84651655, 305626.52728612, 326897.20805569, 346109.43584756]),`

Comment: Thanks, I was able to try on another machine where I can update the package, and got the result -- a meaningful (and straight) trendline.

Comment: @RobRaymond I'd like to share your response as the solution (upgrading statsmodels to 0.12.2), if you want to put that as a full answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- check versions of **plotly** and **statsmodels**
- works with **plotly** 5.2.1 and **statsmodels** 0.12.2

```
import plotly
import statsmodels

print(plotly.__version__, statsmodels.__version__)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me on those versions either. It must be related to something else.

Comment: This does not work for me with plotly 5.11.0 and statsmodels 0.13.5.

Comment: @mad plotly 5.11 and statsmodel 0.13.5 give me a straight line as expected

Comment: @RobRaymond The statsmodel version has nothing do to with the issue. The root cause was bug in plotly (see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75057557/15059132)) which has just now been fixed in [plotly 5.12](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/releases/tag/v5.12.0).

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**: This bug has been fixed in [plotly 5.12.0](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/releases/tag/v5.12.0)

Original answer:

This is currently an open bug with plotly, see https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/3683

[Workaround](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/3683#issuecomment-1375581490) for now:
Edit your ... plotly/express/_core.py and change [the line](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/master/packages/python/plotly/plotly/express/_core.py#L331)

```py
x = x.astype(int) / 10**9  # convert to unix epoch seconds
```

to

```py
x = x.astype(np.int64) / 10**9  # convert to unix epoch seconds
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the following code before making the figure:

```
df['month'] = (df['month'] -ps.Timestamp(“1970-01-01”)) // pd.Timedelta(‘1s’)
```

[Reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#from-timestamps-to-epoch)